# How to load point data in JSON format from an URL into Qgis using the python console?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, url

Via an URL: http://www.odaa.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=c3097987-c394-4092-ad1d-ad86a81dbf37 I have what appears to be a file in JSON format that contains points which I want into QGIS directly from the URL, preferably with the Python console. Within the JSON file columns for longitude and latitude are present.

Do any of you know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look like (parts of) roads, there are always 2 point coordinates: `POINT_1_LAT`, `POINT_1_LNG`, `POINT_2_LAT`, `POINT_2_LNG`

I wrote a small script (using the example from the [QGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider)) that will create a layer and load the data:

```
import urllib, json
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import qgis
from qgis.core import *

# create memory layer
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "point_data", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("_id", QVariant.Int),
                    QgsField("ROAD_TYPE",  QVariant.String),
                    QgsField("ORGANISATION", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields() # tell the vector layer to fetch changes from the provider

# download data and parse it
url = 'http://www.odaa.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=c3097987-c394-4092-ad1d-ad86a81dbf37'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

# iterate points and add to layer
for point in data['result']['records']:
    linestring_feature = QgsFeature()
    point1 = QgsPoint(float(point['POINT_1_LNG']), float(point['POINT_1_LAT']))
    point2 = QgsPoint(float(point['POINT_2_LNG']), float(point['POINT_2_LAT']))
    linestring = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point1, point2]);
    linestring_feature.setGeometry(linestring)
    linestring_feature.setAttributes([point["_id"], point["ROAD_TYPE"], point["ORGANISATION"]])
    pr.addFeatures([linestring_feature])

# update layer's extent when new features have been added
vl.updateExtents()

# sdd layer to layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

You can use it through the Processing Toolbox - Scripts, or simply paste it in the Python console.

[image: QGIS Processing Toolbox Scripts]

Select WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) as the reference system when the window pops up.